# Do there exist compression ring springs?

Tags: material-selection, tool-selection, terminology, material-identification, metal

I'm not sure what to search for, and I'm hoping you can help me find whatever this might be called:

I'm looking for something that looks like a keyring, but expands with pressure if pressed onto a tube; it then squeezes when released.  Maybe think "metal rubber band".

It needs to be metal for electrical conductivity, ~1mm in thickness, and about 2-3cm in diameter.  (I've scoured Amazon's keyring selection, but everything looks far too strong to expand and bounce back.)

What would something like this be called?  Other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how much it needs to open/stretch.

[External circlips/retaining rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retaining_ring) spring to mind - they're normally installed into a groove, but don't always have to be. Getting them out of a groove (and sometimes in) takes special pliers, but just used on a tube that shouldn't be necessary.

[image: Circlips, via Wikipedia]

<sub>Retaining rings image from Wikipedia https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Axial_Rings.jpg</sub>

Otherwise 1-3 turns cut from a suitably-sized compression spring should work.  You can either buy springs or make them by wrapping wire round something undersized.  Piano strings are a good type of wire for making springs.

The actual effect of squeezing in one direction to expand in the other requires a more complex braided construction. Braided sleeves in (tinned) copper or steel are conductive, but will fray unless you seal the ends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! FYI to others who might find your answer: these are also called "External Retaining Rings" or "C-clips" or Circlips.  E-clips are different, but could be useful depending on the task.  In my case I need "overlapping external retaining rings" for a rotary electrical contact, but haven't found any yet.

Comment: Another term of interest is *slip ring* - that's more like what you're trying to end up with but might give you some pointers